# can't acess the public static method of an class in another class in android(java)

Tags: java, android

i created an class 'MySingleton' which consists of an method 'getInstance(Context con)'. i wanted to access this method bud im getting an error "cant resolve this symbol"
following is the code for MySingleton

```
public class MySingleton {     
.
.
.
public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context)
{
    if(mySingleton == null)
    {
        mySingleton = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return  mySingleton;
}
.
. 
}
```

following is the statement where im getting error
    `MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);` 
error can't resolve the symbol getInstance();
please help me.
thank you

Comment: You don't need a Singleton design pattern for the application class, so long as your are accessing it via Activity / Fragment. Just call getApplication() and cast the object returned to MySingleton

Comment: i didn't get you. but Mysingleton is not an activity/fargment. its like an helper class

Comment: im using mysingleton for volley purpose.

Comment: Why don't you just do it the recommended way then without extending `Application` and using a separate class as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton)? It looks like you are following that anyways...

Comment: thank you, i removed the Application(extends) but still i'm facing the same error....?

Comment: What is `this` in your call? Are you sure its a context?

Comment: im having problem with the method not with the context.once again error is cannot resolve symbol "getInstance()" not the parameter. if it could be the error it will definitely show the error wrong parameter...

Comment: You don't have another `MySingleton` without that method anywhere do you? If you just do `MySingleton.` and let autocomplete do its thing is the method shown as an option in the list?